# Undefined function in ballerina

Tags: function, wso2, undefined, ballerina

I'm new to Ballerina. When I try to execute **"ballerina run MainService.bal"** I'm getting an error saying **undefined function retreiveAllPatientDetails**. This function is defined in another ballerina file which is in the same module as the MainService.bal.Following are the files.

PatientService.bal
[image]

MainService.bal
[image]

What are the possible causes for this and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please paste the code as **text**, not **images**.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I'll follow this in future.

Comment: @SarankiMagenthirarajah Or you can edit your question and paste the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you are trying to run only `MainService.bal` but `retreiveAllPatientDetails` function is defined at the `PatientService.bal`. So, when compiling the `MainService.bal`, that function is not visible.

The solution is that, you have to run the module as `$ ballerina run patient`. This command should be executed from inside of MEDICALINFOSYSTEM directory.

Please refer to https://ballerina.io/learn/structuring-ballerina-code/ for more information on how to structure Ballerina code.